# Why does Pandas Dataframe first function(DataFrame.first("2D")), with appropriate offset value, return empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have DataFrame with a date column and I decide to set that column as the index to perform time series operation. Calling DataFrame.first("1M") returns empty dataframe and DataFrame.last("1M") returns all the data even after sorting the index with DataFrame.sort_index(). In fact calling DataFrame.sort_index() causes this behavior as it worked as expected if I don't call the sort_index().
For example:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({"1":[1,2,3], "2":[2,3,4], "date":["2020-05-29", "2020-05-24", "2020-05-27"]})
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
    print(df)
    df = df.set_index("date").sort_index(ascending=False)
    print(df.first("2D"))
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to do 'ascending=True'  otherwise first isn't likely to return much.

Comment: first is supposed to return initial periods based on the dates from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html). Setting ascending=False affects it in a way not documented. I want to know if it's an expected behavior or a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Since `sort_index()` on dataframe causes the behavior,
we can sort the dataframe before *resetting* the index.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"1": [1, 2, 3], "2": [2, 3, 4], "date": ["2020-05-29", "2020-05-24", "2020-05-27"]})

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df = df.sort_values(by='date').set_index("date")

print(df.first("2D"))
```

```py
date            
2020-05-24  2  3
```

Comment: I also tried `df = df.sort_values(by='date').set_index("date")` but realized setting ascending=False in sort_values() makes it fail. Do you know why it's so? Without setting ascending to False then I will have to use df.last() afterwards.

Comment: @Touchstone `first("2D")` will give you 2 first calendar days, not the first 2 rows from there. If we sort it in descending order, there are no calendar days from the first date, which is the last date. That's why it returns the empty dataframe.

Comment: 2 first calendar days is `2020-05-24` when sorted in ascending order. Could you explain what you mean by there are no calendar days from the first date when sorted in descending order. Does it mean you can't use that fnx when date is in descending order? Also if I sort in descending order `print(df.last("2D"))` returns everything in the dataframe.